# How to create a printable report using html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a form that a user can input data into, save the data to the DB, then print the report. None of my research online has yielded much fruit. I've googled for "printable html template", "how to print html", "How to achieve 'wysiwyp'", etc. Nothing. I read something about media queries, but have yet to research that concept much. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Jon

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on why this is not a good question for SO.

Comment: Okeydoke. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a php / HTML snippet that will do the trick:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST > 0)) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "mydb";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES ('". $_POST['myvar'] ."')";
    $conn->query($sql)
    echo "Successfully inserted data ". $_POST['myvar'] ." into column mycol";
}
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="myvar" >
            <input type="submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Put in your database details, save the file as index.php on your web server (XAMPP for example if you're using Windows) and execute it by opening the file with a web browser.

Comment: thank you for response. I'm thinking I should be able to figure out how to do the insertion of the data, etc. The main obstacle that I'm wondering is how to layout my html/css to make the report printable. Seems from A. Williams that this is not a good topic for discussion here, but I appreciate your effort.